# GDB: Append to solib-search-path

Tags: gdb

How can I append to the contents of **solib-search-path**?

I would like to do smothing like:

```
set solib-search-path $(solib-search-path):some/other/path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a simple built-in way to do this.  There are two less simple ways, though.

The simplest of the two ways is to use Python scripting to change the setting.  From Python it is easy to get the current value and modify it as a string.

The harder way is to use a combination of `set logging`, `shell`, and `source` to do it.  The idea is to print the current value to a file, rewrite the file to be the new `set` command, and then `source` the result.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to do this using Python commands?